# Inverse of given operator not continous

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity

Let $E = C[0,1]$ and $F = C^1[0,1]$ and equip both with the infinity norm $\|\cdot\|_\infty$.
Prove that the inverse of the operator $T: E\to F$ with $(Tf)(t) = \int_0^t f(s)\,\mathrm{d}s$ is not continuous.

Comment: Since $T $ is linear, prove that it is not continuous at the zero function.

Comment: To prove that $T^{-1}$ is unbounded (i.e. discontinuous at $0$), you could construct a sequence $\{f_n\}_n$ such that $\|f_n\|_\infty =1$ and $\lim_n \|Tf_n\|_\infty =0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of a sequence $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ within the unit ball $B_1(F)\subset F$ such that $\|T^{-1}f_n\|_{\infty}\to \infty$. Let $f_n(t) = 1-e^{-nt}$. As $nt\geq 0$, we have that $0 < e^{-nt}\leq 1$, so therefore we also have $0\leq f_n(t) < 1$ (implying $\|f_n\|_{\infty} < 1$). Also, $$f_n(t) = \int_0^t ne^{-ns}\,\mathrm{d}s$$ so $(T^{-1}f_n)(s) = ne^{-ns}$. This gives us $\|T^{-1}f_n\|_{\infty} = n$, which is unbounded. Therefore, $T^{-1} : F\to E$ is not continuous.